# Why using `MPI_Type_vector` for specifying a stride gap?

Tags: mpi, stride

In the MPI documentation I read that the difference between `MPI_Type_vector` and `MPI_Type_contiguos` is that the first allows to specify a stride gap between the elements of the array.

Why one should be interested in doing that instead of using simply a `MPI_Type_contiguous`?

Comment: can you please edit your post and fix the typo in `MPI_Type_contiguos()` ?

Comment: Having a datatype with repeating pattern with a gap (stride) allows one to send from or receive into a part of an array, e.g., a submatrix, a slice from a higher-dimensional matrix, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see `MPI_Type_contiguous()` as a special case of `MPI_Type_vector()` with no stride.

For example, in Fortran, arrays are column major. so if you consider the following array

```
integer :: A(n,m)
```

The derived datatype for a column can be obtained with

```
CALL MPI_Type_contiguous(n, MPI_INTEGER, newtype, ierr)
```

or

```
CALL MPI_Type_vector(n, 1, 1, MPI_INTEGER, newtype, ierr)
```

or

```
CALL MPI_Type_vector(1, n, n, MPI_INTEGER, newtype, ierr)
```

But the only way to describe a row is via `MPI_Type_vector()`

```
CALL MPI_Type_vector(m, 1, n, MPI_INTEGER, newtype, ierr)
```

Note that if you want to send/receive several rows at once, you will need to resize the datatype, so the full sequence would be

```
CALL MPI_Type_vector(m, 1, n, MPI_INTEGER, tmptype, ierr)
CALL MPI_Type_size(MPI_INTEGER, integer_size, ierr)
CALL MPI_Type_create_resized(tmptype, 0, integer_size, newtype, ierr)
CALL MPI_Type_free(tmptype, ierr)
```